# Deleting value from array in Javascript using method (function)

Tags: javascript, methods

Im just creating a simple game using javascript. im just stuck in deleting a value from array.
I have an array for player one ( for player one values are generated by random number). Value is called in a div when the current random number generated is displayed ....
Now i want to delete value from array if the current generated random number is similar to value in array of player one.

```
var playerone_arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  playerone_arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  document.getElementById("playerone_no").innerHTML += playerone_arr[i];
}

function player_one_play() {
  var random_no = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  document.getElementById("player_result").innerHTML = random_no;
  for (var i = 0; i < playerone_arr.length; i++) {
    if (playerone_arr[i] == random_no) {
      playerone_arr.splice(playerone_arr[i], 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) expects an index, so provide the index of the element you want to remove.

```
var index = playerone_arr.indexOf(random_no);
if (index >= 0 ) {
    playerone_arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```